# After upgrading from drush 7 to 8 with multisites, using drush from site directory cannot find drupal 7 (Windows)

Tags: drush, multi-sites

Previously with drush 7, I could `cd` to the site directory (e.g. `sites/example1.com`) and perform drush commands (e.g. `drush st`). Now with drush 8, unless I specify the root in the drush command, it cannot bootstrap past level 0:

```
$ drush st
 PHP configuration      :  C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.9\php.ini
 PHP OS                 :  WINNT
 Drush script           :  C:/Users/Dan/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php
 Drush version          :  8.1.18
 Drush temp directory   :  C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local\Temp
 Drush configuration    :
 Drush alias files      :


$ drush st -r c:/wamp64/www/drupal7
           Drupal version                  :  7.64
 Site URI                        :  http://example.com
 Database driver                 :  mysql
 Database hostname               :  localhost
 ....
```

I do have a `sites/sites.php` file:

```
 <?php 
 $sites = [
    'dev.example1.com' => 'example1.com',
    'dev.example2.com' => 'example2.com',
    'dev.example3.us' => 'example3.us',
 ];
```

Local site `sites\example1\drushrc.php` file:

```
<?php
$options['l'] = "http://dev.example1.com";
$options['r'] = 'c:/wamp64/www/drupal7';
```

Without the -r root option, drush doesn't load the `sites.php` or the `drushrc.php`.

Drush is installed globally using composer. It was not installed as part of drupal 8.

MORE INFO: Oddly, drush 8 is working with drupal 8 in a multisite directory.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that drush 8 does not support drupal projects that were not built with composer. Drush 7 does not have this requirement. I added this `composer.json` to the drupal 7 root directory:

```
{
  "require": { 
    "drush/drush": "~8.0"
  }, 
  "extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
       ".": [ "type:drupal-core" ]
    } 
  } 
}
```

I [found this in an issue](https://github.com/webflo/drupal-finder/issues/35) for project `drupal-finder`, which seems to be used by the Drupal 9 `Drupal Launcher`. I'm guessing that drush 8 has [similar code](https://github.com/webflo/drupal-finder/blob/master/src/DrupalFinder.php#L106).